# Write data in a column using CSV module in python

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, writer

I have written my beautiful soup code to create ouput in the following format

```
Quatermass 2
Ghostbusters
Life of Brian
```

I'd now like to write this into a csv file. However the only csv write function I'm familiar with is write_row. When I use this it prints only the last 'title_content' object I scrape ie ->Life of Brian

My python code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import csv

html = ['table.html']

with open("table.html", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

outputfilename = 'row_writer.csv'
print(outputfilename)

outputfile = open(outputfilename, 'w')          #wb = write and binary - indicates file open for writing in binary
writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
writer.writerow(['Title'])

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")
for name in soup.find_all("td", {"width": "41%"}, string=re.compile(r'^(?!Title$)')):
    title_content = ((name).get_text())
    print(title_content)

writer.write_row([title_content])
```

Can anyone help with a way to write my entire content into a csv column please?

HTML

```
    <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
                <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Quatermass 2</strong></td>

    <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
                <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Ghostbusters</strong></td>

    <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
                <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Life of Brian</strong></td>
```

Comment: You need to indent the line where you write the row, otherwise it’s not in the loop block. Indentation matters in Python.

Comment: great, thanks Peter. though my column data now prints like Title, NULL, Quatermass 2, NULL, Ghostbusters, NULL, Life of Brian, NULL. Every 2nd cell in my output is blank. any idea why?

Comment: use pandas, it's lovely

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the titles all are with the tag `<strong>`. so what you can do is create a list of the text with that tag, then convert to a table that is written to file using pandas. You can also do it with writer, but I like using pandas as you can manipulate the tables as needed.

```
html = ''' <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
                <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Quatermass 2</strong></td>

    <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
                <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Ghostbusters</strong></td>

    <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
                <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Life of Brian</strong></td>'''




import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
titles = soup.find_all('strong')

titles_list = [each.text for each in titles ]

df = pd.DataFrame(titles_list, columns=['Title'])

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
           Title
0   Quatermass 2
1   Ghostbusters
2  Life of Brian
```